# Append, C-strings and struct member functions

Tags: arrays, c-strings, pointer-to-member

How I can add what characters I want to the end of what the user would type in. Also a pointer is being passed into the `wordArr[]` if that helps at all

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;
struct Word {
    string english;
    string pigLatin;
};




void convertToPigLatin(Word wordArr[], int size){   //converts given word array into piglatin
    char a = 'a';
    char y = 'y';
    char begins;
    int i = 0;
    
    for(int index = 0; index < size; index++){
        wordArr->pigLatin[index] = wordArr->english[index];
    }
    
    
    for(int index = 0; index < size; index++){
        
        if(isspace(wordArr->english[index])){
            
            i = index - 1;
            wordArr->pigLatin.append(i, 'a');
            i++;
            wordArr->pigLatin.append(i, 'y');
            
        }
    }
```

I've tried moving around whats within the append parameters, I also tried doing the += operator to show hoping that it would take whatever i type then add ay to the end of it
`wordArr->pigLatin += "ay";`but it adds it to the beginning and not at the end

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with the academic honesty rules for your school. I think most schools cover this in new student orientation.

Comment: I think you should remove the part about academic honesty rules from your question entirely.  It doesn't add value to your question and incites unnecessary contention.  Edit your uquestion and delete everything before "...how can I add what characters".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints:

- using `wordArr->`.. means you're treating `wordArr` as if it is a pointer to a single `Word` object, not an array, which seems inconsistent with the naming.  You want `wordArr[i].`... to access the ith element of the array.
- `wordArr->pigLatin[index]` is accessing the index'th character in the string `pigLatin` which seems incorrect, unless `size` is actually the length of the strings, and not the size of the `wordArr` array (which seems more likely)
- the method call `pigLatin.append(i, 'a')` will append i copies of the character `'a'` to the end of the string.  This seems unlikely to be what you actually want.

Generally in C++ you want to avoid using C constructs like raw arrays and C-strings.  You want to use `std::string` (which you are) and `std::vector` instead.